# Order require scripts / dependencies with laravel-mix and webpack

Tags: node.js, laravel, webpack, laravel-mix

this the content of my **`/laravel/webpack.mix.js`** :

```
    mix
       .js([
            'resources/assets/js/jquery.js',
            'resources/assets/js/plugin.js'
           ], 'public/js/my_app.js');
```

The content of **`/resources/assets/js/jquery.js`** is :

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
```

The content of **`/resources/assets/js/plugin.js`** is the local code written like this :

```
(function($) { 

    // plugin script 

})(jQuery);
```

When the plugin.js script **is written locally** (as above), it is **loaded BEFORE jQuery** in my_app.js (e.g *plugin.js* **THEN** *jQuery*)

BUT

when I extract plugin.js with "require" or "import" instruction directly from
 node_modules**, e.g `require('plugin')` written in plugin.js, **the order is OK** :
*jquery.js* is loaded first **THEN** *plugin.js*.

My question:

I want to load jquery.js BEFORE plugin.js.

So, How to do to respect the order EVEN when the plugin.js is a local script?

Comment: Has anyone been able to fix this yet because I'm having the same problem with summernote and jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel mix provides feature where you can extract vendor libraries to `vendor.js`. But you have to make sure your application code `app.js` is called after your `vendor.js`.

```
<script src="/js/manifest.js"></script>
<script src="/js/vendor.js"></script>
<script src="/js/app.js"></script>
```

Reference - https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mix#vendor-extraction

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But when I try your solution it tells me that Bootstrap requires jQuery.
My extract order :


.extract([
    'jquery',
    'bootstrap-sass',
    'jquery-ui',
    'jquery-ui/ui/effect',
    'jquery-ui/ui/widgets/autocomplete',
    'jquery-ui/ui/widgets/datepicker',
    'jquery-ui/ui/widgets/menu',
    'tipsy/src/javascripts/jquery.tipsy',
  ]).
Same order than you for HTML view

Comment: I tried with mix.autoload in addition with mix.extract(). It resolves the "bootstrap needs JQuery" problem but still have the main problem :/

Answer (score 0):

After the .extract call, add

```
autoload({
    jquery: ['$', 'jQuery', 'window.jQuery']
});
```

So,

```
mix.js(...).extract(...).autoload(...);
```

Edit : just saw your response that you tried this

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer :), but as i said before, I tried with mix.autoload in addition with mix.extract(). It resolves the "bootstrap needs JQuery" problem but still have the main problem :/ (local scrips VS require plugins). Lol sorry, just saw your response that you saw I tried this :D